# Elegant way to safely .text.strip() in BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup under Python for quite a bit of data scraping and cleaning and often append `.text.strip()` to a soup.find command. Example: `foo_stuff = soup.find("foo").text.strip()`

In certain cases a `soup.find` does not find anything, and the resulting `.text.strip()` breaks.  As I see it I can handle this a few ways:

- Write `.find` queries that always return something -- *I am not a clever enough person to frame my queries like this in a clean fashion.*
- use try/except statements on every `.text.strip()` -- *Code is ugly.*
- I could patch the .find command to have a try/except, or include a `.myfind` command that does something similar -- *This involves me patching things and potentially throwing off collaborators.*

Do other folks out there have better/clever solutions to solve this?

Edit: Right now I'm using a boring ol' function to try/except `.text.strip()`:

```
def text_strip(soup_search):
    if soup_search != None:
        return soup_search.text.strip()
    else:
        return ""
```

Comment: could you give me an idea of the sorts of things you're scraping for?

Comment: Ah they would all be webpages (hence BeautifulSoup).  Um, should I be more specific?

Comment: Many webpages use microformats: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microformat You could use this idea to make better use of your searches.

Comment: Interesting: http://microformats.org/wiki/implementations -- I'll check it out.  So far using Chrome's "Inspect Elements" is pretty awesome but I'll try this out too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a real better approach nowadays, which is more secure.

```
my_str = soup.find("span").get_text(strip = True)
```

See https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html?highlight=strip#get-text

Comment: The result is not the same as `.get_text().strip()`. Your version removes also whitespace between elements, doing `.strip()` after only preceding and following.

Answer (score 6):

How about writing a plain old function?

```
def find_stripped(soup, what):
  found = soup.find(what)
  if found is not None:
    return found.text.strip()
  # maybe:
  # return ""
```

Now you can: `foo_stuff = find_stripped(soup, "foo")`

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot to mention that's my current implementation, but for stylistic reasons I'm trying to have things go variable.mymethod.  I dunno if that's making life unnecessarily hard for me :) but I figured this is all part of the learning process.

Comment: I'd rather go for a set of my own custom functions that cleanly do what I need than for adding extra methods via patching. (If you're into monkey-patching, take a look at Ruby where it is a cultural norm.) But if you want to learn about the inner workings, then patching is the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

I think the safest way is to check whether `.find()` returned a instance of type `tag`.

```
from bs4.element import Tag
foo_stuff = soup.find("foo") 

if isinstance(foo_stuff, Tag):  
  # do something with foo_stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to use Beautiful Soup's function parameter when searching:

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function

Example:

```
tagsWithStrippedText = bs.find_all(tagsAndStripText);

def tagsAndStripText(tag):
  if tag.text:
    tag.string = tag.text.strip()
  return True
```

I find it more expressive. Be careful as setting the string overwrites tags inside it.